# The buttons on the top bar are no longer right-aligned on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, responsive-design

Yesterday the top bar on mobile (iOS Safari) looked like this:

[image]

Now it looks like this:

[image]

And this is not only limited to mobile devices. It can also be replicated by narrowing the width of your browser (Firefox on MacOS in this case) to the point that your reputation, badges, and search bar disappear:

[image]

Was this a deliberate decision, or did a bug got introduced?

Comment: Reproduced in Firefox, Android 12

Comment: My screen is always filled, both vertically and horizontally, so no way to test this for sure.

Comment: There is also a slight misposition in horizontal mode.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome, Windows 11: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQc0V.png

Comment: We're working on rolling back the PR that caused this. Hold tight - and thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been fixed and restored in production. We were making some accessibility improvements which broke some of the layout and didn't catch this.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Can you please let us know what were you trying to do to the top bar w.r.t. accessibilty?

Comment: @RandomPerson, sure! This quick fix will in no way impede that work, just reverting the commit, fixing on prod, and then we'll pick back up with extra testing.  The gist of it is fixing up the aria roles per [Required ARIA parents role not present](https://accessibilityinsights.io/info-examples/web/aria-required-parent/)

Answer (score 13):

I'm afraid this is a bit more serious than "oh no everything is left-aligned!" This change also prevents the top bar from scrolling, which means that it's hard or impossible to access some items on certain screens in certain situations:

[image: Regular site where SE logo and site switcher are cut off but still accessible]

[image: No help or switcher when there are mod flags]

[image: Not even review on Stack Overflow]

(These are all actual screenshots of a phone. And I don't even have the worst combination: Stack Overflow + mod tools.)

When hatsgiving comes around, yet another icon will be added for everyone, making the problem even worse (but I'm hoping this will be resolved before then).